# CNN Layer error Help required for deep learning task

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm encountering problem with changing the shape. What is the reason of appearing that error ?

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected global_max_pooling2d_1 to have shape (2048,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

MY CODE:

```
input_size = (img_size, img_size, 3)
if model_name == "resnet":
    baseModel = ResNet50(
        weights="imagenet",
        include_top=False,
        input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3)
    )

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(headModel)

model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
model.summary()

for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
```

Comment: Have you added batch dimensions to your input? The code works fine on my end.

Comment: Your model does not have classification layers, so of course the output shape does not match with the targets.

Comment: Actually I want my cnn to only extract features which I will pass further to lstm for classification but I am not sure if I need to add any other layer after pooling




        headModel = LSTM(32)(main_input)

    # headModel = Dense(512, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="fc1")(
    #     headModel
    # )
    # headModel = Dropout(0.4)(headModel)

    predictions = Dense(
        3,
        activation="softmax",
        kernel_initializer="he_uniform"
    )(headModel)